# How do I get a tenth part of a second?

Tags: swift, xcode6, osx-yosemite

I try to make something in swift, and now I need to get a tenth part of a second from the system. I've checked the documentation and, from `NSCalendar`, I can take only nanoseconds.

```
func getTime()  {

    let dateNow = NSDate()
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

    let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute | .CalendarUnitSecond | .CalendarUnitNanosecond , fromDate: dateNow)

    let x = CGFloat(components.nanosecond) * -1000000000
    println(x)

    let s = components.second
    cSeconds = s;

    let m  = components.minute     
    let h = components.hour     

     // code... 
}
```

Have you you any idea how can I take this info from the system. O! I think it is ok if I get at least milliseconds, because I think it's much easier to work with it. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One nanosecond is 10<sup>-9</sup> seconds.
Just divide the nanoseconds by 10<sup>8</sup> to get tenth of seconds,
or by 10<sup>6</sup> to get milliseconds.
Example:

```
let dateNow = NSDate()
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute | .CalendarUnitSecond | .CalendarUnitNanosecond , fromDate: dateNow)

let t = components.nanosecond / 100000000
let s = components.second
let m  = components.minute
let h = components.hour

println(String(format:"%02ld:%02ld:%02ld.%01ld", h, m, s, t))
// 14:27:12.3
```

Comment: pff.. It seems i already did that, but i received some strange numbers because i divided by 1 000 000 000 000 . I just have to many 0 :)) Thanks.

Comment: @C-Viorel: The code in your question actually *multiplies* by -1,000,000,000 instead of dividing.

Answer (score 2):

There are 1,000,000,000 nanoseconds in a second, and 1,000 milliseconds in a second. So you can simply divide your nanoseconds by 1,000,000 to convert to milliseconds, and round the result for the closest millisecond interval.

```
let milliseconds = round(CGFloat(components.nanosecond) / 1000000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use NSDateFormatter to get the milliseconds?

```
let dateNow = NSDate()
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss:SSS"
println(dateFormatter .stringFromDate(dateNow))
```

SSS represents milliseconds.